# PHP curl: Yes box not ticking

Tags: php, curl

Really struggling with this. Some help would be greatly appreciated, i have spent an hour with this today already and i feel I've hit a brick wall..

This same exact code used to work perfect, however i am assuming the service has updated some of their code slightly as its not working as it should now, its probably just something simple but i just cant seem to get it working anymore and cant find whats been updated that stops it working.

This code basically visits one page to check a cars mot/tax status, once you visit that page you have to click Yes on the next page which is where im getting stuck at right now, however the code used to work perfect every time, thanks in advance for any help guys.

```
<?
$Vrm = "KS09 FSV";

$url = 'https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle';
$fields = array(
    'Vrm' => urlencode($Vrm),
    'Correct' => urlencode("True")
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$value = explode("value=\"", $result);
$value = explode("\"", $value[1]);


$url = 'https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ViewVehicle';
$fields = array(
    'Vrm' => urlencode($Vrm),
    'viewstate' => urlencode($value[0])
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$res=$dom->loadHTML($result);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$class = 'isUntaxed';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach($divs as $div)
{
    $dateSplit = explode(":", $div->nodeValue);
    echo $dateSplit[0] . " " . $dateSplit[1] . " ";

    $date1 = new DateTime(date(d) . " " . date ( M ) . " " . date( Y ));
    $date2 = new DateTime($dateSplit[1]);

    if ( $date1 > $date2 ) $exp = "Expired";
    else $exp = "Valid for another";

    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
    echo $exp . " " . $diff . " days ago<BR><BR>";
}

$class = 'isValidMot';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach($divs as $div)
{
    $dateSplit = explode(":", $div->nodeValue);
    echo $dateSplit[0] . "<BR>" . $dateSplit[1] . "<BR>";

    $date1 = new DateTime(date(d) . " " . date ( M ) . " " . date( Y ));
    $date2 = new DateTime($dateSplit[1]);
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");

    if ( $date1 > $date2 ) $exp = "Expired";
    else $exp = "Valid for another";

    echo $exp . " " . $diff . " days ago<BR><BR>";
}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New Answer

As per the comments below, you need to uncomment out the following line from both requests:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

The government website has changed the class name of the elements where the expiry data is stored, so instead of `isUntaxed` and `isValidMot`, both divs now have the class `isValid`.

Just as a side note, where you're creating the `DateTime` object for today's date, you can just use the following:

```
$date1 = new DateTime(date('d M Y'));
```

which is shorter and doesn't produce warnings such as

> **Notice**: Use of undefined constant d - assumed 'd'

---

### Original Answer

<s>Looking at your code and the website, you're sending the `'Correct' => urlencode("True")` for the first URL (https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle) whereas it needs to be submitted to the second URL (https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ViewVehicle).</s>

If you go to the [first URL](https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle) manually in your browser, you will see that you only need the registration number on the first page. Once that has been submitted, you then need to submit the checkbox on the next page.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've just tried adding the 'Correct' to the second url and im still getting the same result..

Comment: @RyanPatterson you may need further changes to the code as well, on the second page there are 4 hidden inputs that get submitted `viewstate`, `Vrm`, `Make`, and `Colour`. You have `Vrm` and `viewstate` in your code already, and you've added `Correct`, but you may need to add the other 2 to get it to work. The `Make` and `Colour` values are obviously dynamic as well, based on the registration number you pass in.

Comment: Hi, yeah i have added viewstate after a previous update which changes every time so needs to be pulled out the source, ive already tried the Colour and Make and those dont work! this is why im so puzzled!

Comment: @RyanPatterson what's the response you're getting after the request to the first URL? Does that HTML response match the HTML from if you entered the details in the website manually through your browser? I.e. does the script definitely succeed past the first page, and is it the second page that is causing the problem?

Comment: @RyanPatterson ok, so you seem to be getting past the first page successfully. What is the value of `viewstate` when you're executing the second request? If I manually edit the `viewstate` field on the website to an invalid value, I get redirected back to the first page again. If you do `var_dump(urlencode($value[0]));` just before you define the second URL, and see what it gives you.

Comment: will compare that now, the viewstate value will defo change, its different every time. its too long to post here but it picks up the viewstate.. so if you check that page again.

Comment: @RyanPatterson yes, it should be different so be impossible to know if it's exactly correct, but it should be a huge load of random characters (1648 on the request I've got here run manually through browser) so just see if it's something similar to that :)

Comment: Yeah thats what i got, big load of chars. number varies though.. but i cant cant get past the confirm page! :(

Comment: if i add curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); it works, however then that stops my code working under neath as it acts as a browser visit. am totally lost here! need a break i think! my head is hurting! lol

Comment: I've just copied all the code from your original question to my local machine and uncommented out those lines you've just mentioned `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` for both requests. I then get a white screen. It appears that the classes have changed names in the .gov website. Where you previously had `isUntaxed` and `isValidMot`, they have now both changed to `isValid`. If I change the `$class = 'isValidMot';` to `$class = 'isValid';`, I get some output then.

Comment: if thats all it is im gonna kick my self in the face! ha

Comment: @RyanPatterson haha! If it is, I'll update my answer with the correct solution :)

Comment: ✓ Taxed Tax due 01 January 2018 Valid for another 179 days ago

✓ MOT Expires 26 July 2017 Valid for another 20 days ago

god damn! spent about 3 hours but didnt check that. as if! haha

Comment: Thanks! a lot mate!

Comment: @RyanPatterson no worries! I've updated the answer with the actual solution now, if you wouldn't mind giving me the green tick please! :)